# Where should I ask a question about metrics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to come up with a quantitative metric for measuring customer retention rate for my specific business model.  Where should I ask?

Data Science seems like it might be appropriate, but Project Management, Startup, and maybe Mathematics also seem like possible places.

A Metrology SE would be ideal, but unfortunately does not exist.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail of what exactly you'd hope to ask? I'm a mod at Startups and it sounds like we *should* be able to help, but I'd need to see a bit more about what you are looking to ask specifically.

Comment: Basically, I have a tutoring company where my tutors (contractors) are working individually with students.  I'd like to measure the extent to which these students turn into "repeat customers" for each tutor.  My plan so far is to do a simple ratio of (students with addl sessions)/(total students).  But, it might be more useful to weigh this by the **number** of followup sessions, or perhaps the frequency of followups over time.  We also have to consider the natural attrition of students over time (add/drop courses, etc).

Comment: First off, sorry for taking so long to get back to you. Second, that sounds like an interesting question. I spoke with another mod about this, and I think it sounds like it could be on-topic on [startups.se]. So yeah, I'm not sure if that's your preferred target, because I certainly acknowledge that we're not data scientists there (at least for the most part), but if you decide that it's your best choice, the door is open.

Comment: If you do elect to post there and you want some help making it fit in (yours would be a new type of question to us), feel free to ping me here or on our chat. Otherwise, good luck! You could always try for a new site on Area 51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned this is my comment, but I'll say it here for good measure: [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com/) might be a good fit for you.

You can read our [help/on-topic](https://startups.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for more details, but it sounds like we could probably help, depending on what specifically you're looking to ask.

There are a couple things that we probably wouldn't be able to help with. Notably:

- What do you think of this formula? (too localized, opinion-based)
- I need to come up with a formula, what should it be? (too broad, opinion-based)

But if you can come up with a good start for your formula and a relatively objective question, we'll definitely be able to help. The difference is subtle, but you can probably look through some questions on the site and find a good answer.

That all said, we can also definitely help you hone in your question if you ask it. It sounds like you have interest to do it right, so that already puts you ahead of a lot of people, and we'd love to work with you to get a great answer. Worst case, I can migrate your question if it turns out it isn't appropriate for us.

Full disclosure, I'm a moderator on Startups so I have ulterior motives in wanting you to post there. :)

Comment: Thanks, I've posted my question [here](https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/what-is-a-sensible-way-to-measure-customer-retention-rate).